# Was CloudSat hit by debris? If so, when, how bad was it, and where was it reported?

Tags: earth-observation, impact, mission-anomaly

Anton Petrov's new video Another Satellite Collided in Space, But Everyone Missed It Until Now (below) is fun to watch, and links to Jonathan McDowell's [tweet string](https://twitter.com/planet4589/status/1426771798276943872) which begins

> Space-Track catalog updated today with a note for object 48078, 1996-051Q:  "Collided with satellite".
> This is a new kind of comment entry - haven't seen such a comment for any other satellites before. Let's look a bit closer:

which (somehow) led me to Scott Tilley's [tweet](https://twitter.com/coastal8049/status/1398115164847677440)

> The mysterious YUNHAI 1-02 continues to send wide band data perhaps saying "reports of my death are greatly exaggerated"

below which I found references to "It's only a flesh wound" and then a SpaceflightResearch [tweet](https://twitter.com/SpacefltResrch/status/1398274326437273601) saying

> I think that the US satellite Cloudsat also shed pieces and kept working, its one of the A Train

Wikipedia's [CloudSat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CloudSat#Impact_on_Radio_Astronomy) doesn't mention a collision.

**Question:** Was CloudSat hit by debris? If so, when, how bad was it, and where was it reported?

Perhaps just an otherwise unexplained drop in power output of one of the solar panels?

---

Comment: Cloudsat had many problems, starting with a severe battery storage failure, but collision does not appear to have been one of them as of a decade ago https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA568401.pdf Momentum wheel problems finally put it to sleep http://www.cloudsat.cira.colostate.edu/

Comment: @OrganicMarble What? doesn't Twitter fact-check each tweet before allowing them to appear on the internet? Negative results are hard to probe, if a couple of authoritative sources fail to mention a collision that may be sufficient for an answer. The "bold, innovative... radical" problem-solving in the recovery and lessons-learned document may need a question of its own.